# Tic Tac Toe isn't showing winner correctly with lists

Tags: python

In my tic tac toe game, after 4 turns, it declares X (the first player) to be the winner even if not. I don't know what im missing and it was working when just checking columns but now with rows it doesn't. I have a feeling it's a problem when I am calling the function with the letter but I'm not entirely sure.

```py
moves = [["1", "2", "3"],
         ["1", "2", "3"],
         ["1", "2", "3"]]

def win(letter):
  if(moves[0][0] == letter and
     moves[1][0] == letter and
     moves[2][0] == letter):
    print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
    quit()
  elif(moves[0][1] == letter and
       moves[1][1] == letter and
       moves[2][1] == letter):
    print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
    quit()
  elif(moves[0][2] == letter and
       moves[1][2] == letter and
       moves[2][2] == letter ):
    print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
    quit()
  elif(moves[0][0] == letter and
       moves[0][1] == letter and
       moves[0][2]):
    print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
    quit()
  elif(moves[1][0] == letter and
       moves[1][1] == letter and
       moves[1][2]):
    print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
    quit()
  elif(moves[2][0] == letter and
       moves[2][1] == letter and
       moves[2][2]):
    print("~~~ " + letter + " WON!!! CONGRATS!!!! ~~~")
    quit()
def playerInput():
  player1 = input("Where do you want to place your X, player 1? (row number, space, number)")
  moves[int(player1[0]) - 1][int(player1[2]) - 1] = "X"
  player2 = input("Where do you want to place your O, player 2? (row number, space, number)")
  moves[int(player2[0]) - 1][int(player2[2]) - 1] = "O"
  boardDraw()
def boardDraw():
  print("1| "+moves[0][0]+" | "+moves[0][1]+" | "+moves[0][2]+" |")
  print(" |---+---+---|")
  print("2| "+moves[1][0]+" | "+moves[1][1]+" | "+moves[1][2]+" |")
  print(" |---+---+---|")
  print("3| "+moves[2][0]+" | "+moves[2][1]+" | "+moves[2][2]+" |")
  win("X")
  win("O")
  playerInput()

print("OK SO....\nPlayer 1 is X\nPlayer 2 is O\nGOOOOO!!")

boardDraw()
```

Comment: Hint: compare the form of the first three `if` cases to the form of the latter three.

Comment: BTW, questions about implementing tic-tac-toe generally get into "needs more focus" or "opinion-based" territory quickly, since there are a lot of ways to write e.g. the win-detection algorithm and a fair amount of room to debate which is best.

Comment: That's really interesting, didn't know there was that much contention in the stack-overflow tic-tac-toe community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming part of your problem has to do with the fact that in some of your `if` cluases, you check the first two squares or equal to `letter`, but not the third. Most objects in Python, except for things like `None` or `0` will be evaluated to `True`. So If there's a non-zero number in your array, or a character, it will be evaluated to `True`. This causes the program to think the player won when a line of only two things are formed.

Also, you six specific win conditions, and there are definitely more than the ones you specified to win in Tic Tac Toe. I would suggest a more logical (and readable) approach of consolidating the win scenarios together. For example, you can check all the horizontal and vertical win conditions in one loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    if ((moves[i][0] == moves[i][1] == moves[i][2] == letter) or
         (moves[0][i] == moves[1][i] == moves[2][i] == letter):
        # do win-condition stuff here
```

Finally, I would recommend checking for invalid moves, since your current code would just let the user over-write existing moves.

Comment: Thanks, its super readable. I need to get used to for loops more lol. Definitely doing invalid moves now!

Answer (score 2):

You're clearly missing 2 winning cases:

```
moves[0][0] == moves[1][1] == moves[2][2]
```

and:

```
moves[0][2] == moves[1][1] == moves[2][0]
```

I'd rather rewrite your winning detection function as:

```
def win(letter) :
    for i in range(3) :  # rows
        if set(moves[i]) == set([letter]) :
            print( 'WIN' )
            quit()
    for x in zip(moves[0], moves[1], moves[2]) :  # columns
        if set(x) == set([letter]) :
            print( 'WIN' )
            quit()

    # you have completely missed the part below...
    if set(moves[i][i] for i in range(3)) == set([letter]) : # one diagonal
        print( 'WIN' )
        quit()
    if set(moves[i][3-i] for i in range(3)) == set([letter]) : # another diagonal
        print( 'WIN' )
        quit()
```

or even more compact:

```
def win(letter) :
    possible_wins = [ set(moves[i]) for i in rage(3) ] +  # rows
        [ set(x) for x in zip(moves[0], moves[1], moves[2]) ] +  # columns
        [ set(moves[i][i] for i in range(3)) ] +  # diagonal
        [ set(moves[i][3-i] for i in range(3)) ]  # another diagonal
    if any( p == set([letter]) for p in possible_wins ) :
        print( 'WIN' )
        quit()
```

Comment: `set([letter])` is more neatly written as `{letter}`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel agree, just did not want to confuse the OP